# Couldn't connect to SQL server localhost PHP 5.6

Tags: php, mysql, database, xampp, localhost

pls help me. I got this error message while accessing index.php on localhost, I already import all tables on database. I'm using php 5.6 and xampp 3.2.2. Anyone can help?

> Couldn't connect to SQL server

and here's my code on engine.php

**engine.php**

```
 <?php 
class database_abc
  {
    var $server,
        $host,
        $user,
        $password,
        $database;

    function __construct($db_name = '', $db_password = '', $db_user = '', $db_host = 'localhost', $debug = '')
    {
      $this->host = $db_host;
      $this->user = $db_user;
      $this->password = $db_password;
      $this->database = $db_name;

      $this->open();
    }

    function open()
    {
      $this->server = @mysql_connect($this->host, $this->user, $this->password) or die("Couldn't connect to SQL server");
      @mysql_select_db($this->database, $this->server);
    }

    function query($sql, $debug = 0)
    {

      if($debug)
        echo "database/query :<strong>$sql</strong>:<br>\n";


      $result = @mysql_query($sql, $this->server);

      if( ($sql[0] == 'i') || ($sql[0] == 'I') )
        return mysql_insert_id();

      while( $row = @mysql_fetch_array($result) )
        $data[] = $row;


      if(isset($data)){
      return $data;
      }

    }

    function queryItem($sql, $debug = 0)
    {
      $result = $this->query($sql." LIMIT 0,1", $debug);
      return $result[0][0];
    }
  };


    $db = new database_abc("qwerty", "admin", "root", "localhost");

?>
```

Comment: Please check if mysql server is running first

Comment: Make sure you use proper username and password in local normally username is root and password is blank.

Comment: Why do you suppress error messages using `@` and don' check for other errors using `mysql_error`?

Comment: Please do **not** use @ , it is not a good practice since it suppresses the error or warning which will be hard to debug for developer, which is probably why you are here now..

Comment: @Naruto thanks mate, now I know the problem.

Comment: Please don't use the `mysql_` api unless you absolutely must, it is removed in newer versions of PHP.  Look into `mysqli_` or `PDO` instead.

Answer (score 1):

**Loading the Driver at PHP Startup**
To load the SQLSRV driver when PHP is started, first move a driver file into your extension directory. Then, follow these steps:

1. To enable the SQLSRV driver, modify php.ini by adding the following
   line to the extension section, changing the filename as appropriate:

> extension=php_sqlsrv_72_ts.dll

On Linux, if you have downloaded the prebuilt binaries for your distribution:

> extension=php_sqlsrv_72_nts.so

If you have compiled the SQLSRV binary from source or with PECL, it will instead be named sqlsrv.so:

> extension=sqlsrv.so

2. To enable the PDO_SQLSRV driver, the PHP Data Objects (PDO)
   extension must be available, either as a built-in extension, or as a
   dynamically loaded extension.

On Windows, the prebuilt PHP binaries come with PDO built-in, so there is no need to modify php.ini to load it. If, however, you have compiled PHP from source and specified a separate PDO extension to be built, it will be named php_pdo.dll, and you must copy it to your extension directory and add the following line to php.ini:

> extension=php_pdo.dll

On Linux, if you have installed PHP using your system's package manager, PDO is probably installed as a dynamically loaded extension named pdo.so. The PDO extension must be loaded before the PDO_SQLSRV extension, or loading will fail. Extensions are usually loaded using individual .ini files, and these files are read after php.ini. Therefore, if pdo.so is loaded through its own .ini file, a separate file loading the PDO_SQLSRV driver after PDO is required.

To find out which directory the extension-specific .ini files are located, run php --ini and note the directory listed under Scan for additional .ini files in:. Find the file that loads pdo.so -- it is likely prefixed by a number, such as 10-pdo.ini. The numerical prefix indicates the loading order of the .ini files, while files that do not have a numerical prefix are loaded alphabetically. Create a file to load the PDO_SQLSRV driver file called either 30-pdo_sqlsrv.ini (any number larger than the one that prefixes pdo.ini works) or pdo_sqlsrv.ini (if pdo.ini is not prefixed by a number), and add the following line to it, changing the filename as appropriate:

> extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_72_nts.so

As with SQLSRV, if you have compiled the PDO_SQLSRV binary from source or with PECL, it will instead be named pdo_sqlsrv.so:

> extension=pdo_sqlsrv.so

Copy this file to the directory that contains the other .ini files.

If you have compiled PHP from source with built-in PDO support, you do not require a separate .ini file, and you can add the appropriate line above to php.ini.

3. Restart the Web server.

Comment: you could have just put the link of microsoft documentation....this copy - paste...